# Connectionstring de acordo com cenário

Tags: asp.net, mvc, connectionstring

Olá, bom dia!

Estou com um projeto onde existe dois cenários, que é homologação e produção. Neste mesmo projeto eu criei duas `connectionstrings`, configurando uma para cada cenário.

No sistema estes cenários são divididos em subdomínios, como homolog.dominio.com.br e o próprio dominio.com.br.

Agora vem a pergunta:
Existe uma forma de criar uma configuração para a `connectionstring` se adaptar ao cenário? Quando eu acessar o homolog ele pega automaticamente a `connectionstring` da homologação.

Está assim:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring_homolog" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx; User ID=xxxxxx; pwd=xxxxxxx;" />
    <add name="connectionstring_prod" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx; User ID=xxxx; pwd=xxxxx;" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Lembrando que estou utilizando ASP.Net MVC.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Você pode configurar a web.config para trocar com Debug e Release.
Que tal?

Comment: Olá Jhonathan, eu estou tentando fazer através de uma sessão, não sei se é uma boa prática, mais como seria essa ideia? Poderia explicar? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente você deverá olhar dentro do sua aplicação no Web.Config

Na sessão do web.config colocar o seguinte código:

```
  <connectionStrings configSource="WebConnStrDevelopment.config">
    <!-- @configSource será modificado na publicação. Ver Web.Release.config -->
  </connectionStrings>
```

Agora no seu Web.Release.config adicione o seguinte código:

```
 <connectionStrings configSource="WebConnStrProduction.config" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(configSource)" />
```

Adicione agora 2 novos arquivos config chamados (WebConnStrDevelopment e WebConnStrProduction)

Dentro do arquivo WebConnStrDevelopment.config adicione o seguinte código:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring"  //adicionar conexão de dev />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Dentro do arquivo WebConnStrProduction.config adicione o seguinte código:

```
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring"  //adicionar conexão de prod/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Você pode ler mais aqui no site da [MSDN](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations)

Comment: Vou verificar, muito obrigado Jhonathan!

Comment: @Bruno Quando for publicar ou debugar local, basta trocar de Debug para Release para alternar entre as conections